# EF using skip and take on stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

How does `Skip()` and `Take()` work in Entity Framework when calling a stored procedure? I can't access sql profiler to check, but I want to make sure I optimize the amount of data sent between servers.

Say I have the following code, where `MyStoredProcedure` returns 1000+ rows.

```
List<MyComplex_Result> myComplexList = db.MyStoredProcedure()
    .Skip(50)
    .Take(10);
```

Will the `Take(10)` make sure that only 10 of those rows are sent from the database server to the web server, or will all 1000+ rows be sent (though only 10 would be sent to the client)?

Comment: So, bearing in mind @eocron 's advice below, can you self-answer here?

Comment: I'm afraid the debug only returns the name of the SP, not the SQL, that was run, so I still can't verify.

Comment: Regardless of technology used, it would be impossible to incorporate the windowing into the query/queries used by the stored procedure itself. Meaning, even *if* EF had a cleverer way of performing `Skip`/`Take` on the stored procedure's result set than just literally reading and discarding the `Skip` amount and then reading only the `Take` amount (and I doubt it does), the stored procedure will still necessarily retrieve all rows internally. You may find that "optimizing the amount of data sent" may not be the primary concern.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I believe you are right. I'll have to go back to the drawing board on this one. I just liked having filtering and pagination logic in EF rather than the SP, and I did an SP because of the complexity of the query. Seems like the two don't really jive. I guess I'll have to chose one place to handle all.

Comment: Fortunately pagination isn't hard to include on the server side, and if your query really is complex enough to warrant a stored procedure, you probably want the chance to optimize it anyway. The "right" way to do pagination can actually be [quite variable depending on your scenario](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did encounter such requirements before. Originally, my option was to use stored procedure, but when I realize that data could be thousands, using SP no longer became applicable. Here are the two things I did to do this:

1. I created a view where the result of SP is there. Of course, this contains all the records without filter yet. I used that view to manipulate the records via EF where Take and Skip is alreay applicable.
2. I stick to SP. What I did is to design the SP to allow receiving Take and Skip Count. I created the SP as string the use sp_executesql.